# How to use XCTest&OCMock to test method which return block?

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, ocmock

here is my RegisterService.h

```
import "UserObject.h"

@interface RegisterService : NSObject

- (void)sharedInstance;

- (void)registerWithPhoneNum:(NSString *)phoneNum password:(NSString *)password result:(void (^)(UserObject *userObject))successBlock failure:(void (^)(NSNumber *statusCode, NSString *message))failureBlock;
```

so how do I test the register-method with XCTest&OCMock? thanks!!

Comment: To test asynchronous method with XCTest, use expectations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26901979/1271826

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What do you want to test? The implementation of the register method? Or some other code that should call the register method?

Comment: I just want to test login method ...thank you for helping !!!